# Regular Expression iterator is not working in Cpp

Tags: c++, regex, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am working with C++ on Visual Studio 2010 (I don't think its v11 standard but I haven't checked).

I am trying to extract out the IP address of a tracert with the following code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
typedef regex_iterator<string::iterator> regexp;
#define MAX_BUFFER 255
int main() {
    string out;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    smatch m;
    regex e("  1.+\\[(.+)\\]");
    FILE *stream = _popen("tracert SOMEHOSTNAME", "r");
    while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL ) {
        out = buffer;
        regexp rit (out.begin(), out.end(), e);
        regexp rend;
        while (rit != rend) {
            cout << rit->str() << endl;
            ++rit;
        }
    }
    _pclose(stream);
    cout << "Done.";
    cin >> buffer;
}
```

however, the regexp is not extracting out the group itself. Instead it is just spitting back the full line!

I thought I was following examples very carefully but it seems I am not using regex_iterator correctly.

1 - How best can I extract the IP from this string

(Side question - is there a C++ function that will go into the network and get the IP from a hostname just like tracert our pint? Another that will get the mac address just like arp -a)

Comment: Is MSVC the only vendor shipping working regex libraries?

Comment: Simplify. To see whether the regular expression does what you want, feed it a single line. If that works, feed it something more complex. There are too may possible issues in this code to see what's going on, especially since there is no indication of what the text that's being fed to the matcher contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have MSVC, and GNU has broken std::regex support, so I've played with `boost::regex' here:

```
regex e("^\\s*1\\s.*?\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

Note this:

- doesn't assume spaces are spaces rather than tab characters
- doesn't assume exact spacing at the start of the line
- *does* mandate at least 1 space after the `1` character (so it won't match the line starting with `13`, e.g.)
- if uses *non-greedy* matching where possible

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::regex;
using boost::regex_iterator;
#define MAX_BUFFER 255

int main()
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    regex e("^\\s*1\\s.*?\\[(.*?)\\]");

    FILE *stream = popen("cat input.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL)
    {
        typedef regex_iterator<string::iterator> regit;

        string out = buffer;
        regit rit(out.begin(), out.end(), e);
        regit rend;
        while(rit != rend)
        {
            cout << (*rit)[1].str() << endl;
            ++rit;
        }
    }
    pclose(stream);
    cout << "Done.\n";
}
```

This appears to work for `input.txt`:

```
Tracing route to 11.1.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     2 ms     3 ms     2 ms  [157.54.48.1]
2    75 ms    83 ms    88 ms  [11.1.0.67]
3    73 ms    79 ms    93 ms  [11.1.0.1]

Trace complete.
```

printing:

```
157.54.48.1
```

Comment: Ah! What did the trick was saying: `(*rit)[1].str()` instead of just rit->str()! Thanks!